# Copy files of same name into same directory

Tags: command-line, bash, files, copy

I have a large number of folders with a file named `genome.txt` that I need to `cp` into the same folder. I am trying to figure out how I can do this so the files look like `genome1.txt`, `genome2.txt`, etc.. I am looking for a simple solution to this.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You want a solution or a *simple* solution? Can be done, but please define simple. The simplest solution is a script. Please mention if that is simple enough to you.

Comment: That would be perfect! The more simple the better but I am familiar enough with scripting to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Shell script and its usage

This can be done with a simple shell script which makes use of `find ...|while read var ; do ... done` structure ( very common in dealing with filenames ). The bash script below operates on current (top-most) directory and takes single argument for destination.

```
#!/bin/bash
find -name "genome.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' path
do
    base=$(basename --suffix=".txt"  "$path")
    new_path="${1%/}"/"$base"$counter".txt"
    echo "$path" "$new_path"
    counter=$(( $counter +1 ))
done
```

**>>>NOTE<<<**: script uses `echo` just for testing purposes. When you are satisfied with resulting paths, replace `echo` with `mv` to move all filenames or `cp` to copy all filenames.

Example:

```
bash-4.3$ tree
.
├── destination
├── dir1
│   └── genome.txt
├── dir2
│   └── genome.txt
├── dir3
│   └── genome.txt
└── move_enumerated.sh

4 directories, 4 files
bash-4.3$ ./move_enumerated.sh  ./destination
./dir2/genome.txt ./destination/genome.txt
./dir3/genome.txt ./destination/genome1.txt
./dir1/genome.txt ./destination/genome2.txt
```

#### Improving the script for more flexibility

This script can be further improved to make it more general, where user can specify filename , top directory to traverse, and destination all as command-line arguments:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
find "$2"  -name "$1" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' path
do
    base=$(basename --suffix=".txt"  "$path")
    new_path="${3%/}"/"$base"$counter".txt"
    echo "$path" "$new_path"
    counter=$(( $counter +1 ))
done
```

Test run:

```
bash-4.3$ ./move_enumerated.sh "genome.txt"  "./testdir" "./testdir/destination"
./testdir/dir2/genome.txt ./testdir/destination/genome.txt
./testdir/dir3/genome.txt ./testdir/destination/genome1.txt
./testdir/dir1/genome.txt ./testdir/destination/genome2.txt
```

#### Syntax and theory of operation

Over all the script makes use of `command | while read variable ; do ... done` structure. This is a very common approach, and it is frequently used to avoid dealing with `ls` and difficult filenames that can break scripts.

On the left side of the pipe we have `find` command, which takes directory as argument ( and if that's not given, GNU `find` which is used in Linux assumes `.` - the current working directory ). The other options include `-name` which is the specific filename that we are searching, and `-print0` which is used to output results as delimited via non-printable `\0` character. It is frequently used to avoid splitting on newline or other characters, because those characters can potentially appear within the filename itself and as a result break the script.

On the right side of the pipe we have `while IFS= read -r -d '' ; do . . . done` structure. The `while` loop with `read` shell built-in is frequently used to real `stdin` input, which in this case comes from the pipe. `IFS=` `-r` and `-d ''` are necessary to ensure that  we receive filenames safely and recognize that each item is delimited with `\0`.

The rest of the script is fairly easy. We extract basename of the file using `basename` command. Since in this case we're dealing specifically with known extension and expect to have single dot in the filename, we can use `--suffix=".txt"` to strip that part out , leaving `genome` part. We then build new path to file via joining destination , basename, and counter variable. Notice that we use parameter expansion with `"${3%/}"` 
argument (destination folder) in our improved script. This is done to ensure that regardless of whether or not user added `/` character at the command-line ( `./destination` or `./destination/` ),  we extract only bare directory name, and join it via different `/` with basename. Notice also that `counter` variable is not set initially, so the first filename that we receive, will be plain `genome.txt` After than, counter variable will be incremented and thus created and will show up when we deal with other filenames.

For more info , please read [Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly](https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html).